# Discord JDA - How to check how many users a user invited

Tags: java, discord-jda

I'm coding a discord bot and I want to check if a user invited certain amount of people to the server to let him use a command how can I do that?

Comment: You can't. Discord offers no way to track who invited who.

Comment: Is it impossible?

Answer (score 2):

Discord doesn't offer this functionality by itself.

In order to still create a feature like this, you would need to do it by yourself.

Therefore, you need to keep track of all invite links and their number of invites and every time someone joins the server, you can obtain the difference and get the used invite link.

Since every link is created by a user, you can then add 1 to the number of people this user did invite. (You can save this data in a database for example.)

In order to minimize the potential of this system being abused, you need to keep track of the users joining as well. Someone leaving and joining through the same link shouldn't count as multiple persons, should it?

Also keep in mind, that users may leave the server and that some invite links may get deleted. But that's up to you now, I guess. :)