# How can I find out who invited the user using JDA?

Tags: java, discord-jda

I was trying to find out who invited a user to my discord server, but JDA is not correctly displaying the list of who invited.

I was trying to find out who invited the user using:

```
List<Invite> invites = event.getGuild().retrieveInvites().complete();
```

```
            for (Invite invite : invites) {
               System.out.println(invite.getInviter);
            }
```

and get the invitee's id in the same way:

```
            for (Invite invite : invites) {
               System.out.println("Inviter: " + invite.getInviter + "User: " + event.getUser.getId());
            }
```

But this code shows all invites.

Answer (score 2):

Hey here is a way to get inviter as rest action

```java
    private RestAction<User> getInviter(Guild guild, User user) {
        return guild.retrieveAuditLogs().type(ActionType.INVITE_CREATE).map(auditLogs -> {
            for (AuditLogEntry entry : auditLogs) {
                if (entry.getTargetId().equals(user.getId())) {
                    return entry.getUser(); // Returns the inviter
                }
            }
    
            // AuditLogEntry not found
            return null;
        });
    }
```

some examples of using it:

```
// Sync
User user = getInviter(guild, user).complete();
if (user == null) {
  // Do something
  return;
}

// Do something

// Async
getInviter(guild, user).queue(user -> {
  if (user == null) {
    // Do something
    return;
  }
  
  // Do something
});
```

the getInviter method is to find the user who invited another user to a specific Discord server (guild).

How it Works:

1. Retrieving Audit Logs:
   The method starts by retrieving the audit logs of the specified guild using `guild.retrieveAuditLogs()`.
   Audit logs contain records of various actions performed within the guild, including user invitations.
2. Filtering Audit Logs:
   It filters the audit logs to include only entries of type `INVITE_CREATE` using `.type(ActionType.INVITE_CREATE)`.
   This step ensures that only actions related to creating invites are considered.
3. Iterating through Audit Log Entries:
   It iterates through each `AuditLogEntry` within the filtered audit logs.
   An `AuditLogEntry` represents a specific action that occurred in the guild, such as creating an invite.
4. Finding the Inviter:
   For each entry, it checks if the target ID of the action matches the ID of the user for whom the inviter is being sought (`user.getId()`).
   If a match is found, it retrieves the user associated with that audit log entry (`entry.getUser()`), which represents the inviter.
   If no matching entry is found, it returns null, indicating that the inviter could not be determined from the audit logs.

## Synchronous usage

- In synchronous usage, the Inviter retrieval operation is completed immediately, and the retrieved user (or null if not found) is returned.
- This approach is suitable for scenarios where you need the inviter information synchronously and can afford to block the current thread until the operation completes.

## Asynchronous

- In asynchronous usage, a callback (Consumer) is provided to handle the retrieved inviter once the operation completes.
- This approach is preferable in event-driven or non-blocking scenarios where you don't want to block the thread and instead handle the result asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

its not possible right now... You can't get a User from the InviteCode or reverse.

At least not in an easy way - you have to program it yourself via logging.
You can find the complete explanation here:

[Discord JDA - How to check how many users a user invited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62394081/discord-jda-how-to-check-how-many-users-a-user-invited)